# In MySql how do I get row duplication for the case where I pass duplicate IDs in a list?

Tags: sql, mysql

For this MySQL SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID IN(x,y,y,z):
```

I want 4 rows back - ie I WANT row duplication for the case where I pass duplicate IDs in the list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

using the IN() construct, that's not possible.

the only way i can think to do this is with a UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = y
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = y
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = z
```

but in all honesty, i would just do the IN() like you have it and make your app code duplicate the rows as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Put your IDs, including dups in a temp table and join your results on that table.  The join will take care of filtering, but will keep duplicates if it's in the temp table twice

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID IN(x,y,z)
union all 
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID IN(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, **IN** specify a *set of values* to search in (and duplication is a concept that conflict with the set one).

You should use other mean to reach your scope.

Comment: ok thanks. am using in the IN syntax to avoid making seperate db calls for each id. prob gonna have to solve this in the app.